# How use `cin` to pause the program for 10 seconds in C++

Tags: c++, wait, cin

Exacly as stated in the subject: how use **cin** to wait(pause the program) for 10 seconds in C++. I would like to make it act simiral to java's `Thread.wait`.

EDIT:
I am asking about `cin`

Comment: Why do you want to use cin instead of using a function like sleep?

Comment: Regarding your edit: again, `cin` has no notion of timeouts so it will block *until you input something*. There's simply no way around it (not portable at the very least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the way `cin` works, it has no notion of timeouts.

What you really want is, just like you mentioned for Java, to pause your thread. This can be done in several ways...

- C++11: `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));`
- POSIX (Linux et al.): `sleep(10);`
- Windows: `Sleep(10000);` (in milliseconds)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::cout << "Please wait ten seconds, then press \"Enter\":\n";
char ch;
std::cin >> ch;
```